# yo angular-fullstack failure installing on linux local

Tags: angularjs, linux, node.js, npm, bower

Getting the error below. I tried running as sudo and as myself. Same error. This is Linux mint Rosa. The install gets through the yo questionnaire but fails on permissions what looks like it. I am new to Linux. Please help.

```html
create bower.json
fs.js:549
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/mastermean/bower.json'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:549:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1156:15)
    at write (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/commit.js:14:6)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/mem-fs-editor/actions/commit.js:43:7)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:172:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._write (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:160:12)
    at doWrite (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:335:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:321:5)
    at DestroyableTransform.Writable.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/generator-angular-fullstack/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js:248:11)
jul@jul-Inspiron-5558 /home/mastermean $
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this from a terminal:

```
cd ~
mkdir app
cd app
yo angular-fullstack
```

(It may be necessary to run that last command as `sudo yo angular-fullstack` depending on how yeoman was installed.)
It looks like the file bower.json does not have write permission. You may be able to fix the issue by fixing your existing permissions, but the above sequence should get you going without mucking about with permissions.

Comment: Sorry, same error. This is really weird. It installs files and directories into the root of my user. I guarantee that I ran the command from inside the "app" folder.

Comment: can you `cd ~` and then run `ls -l bower.json` to see what the file permissions are on bower.json? Something sounds very odd in your node and/or yeoman setup. Is yeoman installed globally?

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1. Yes, I belive it was with the -g following one of the tutorials

Comment: This is where the files and folders were created: http://i775.photobucket.com/albums/yy38/forfreedom1/Screenshot%20from%202016-01-12%20233016_zps56pjbo0o.png

Comment: Sorry, I have never seen yeoman do that. It's always done it's thing in the directory I'm in. I have never used Mint, but I know there are weird issues in Ubuntu installing node through the repos. Maybe try running a different yeoman generator from the app folder? Maybe there is an error in the generator itself.

Comment: Just deleted all these files and folders. Made sure I am in /app. And it's doing the same thing. What is different yeoman generator? Appreciate your help, Jason.

Comment: The generator you are using is angular-fullstack. The generator is the template that yeoman uses to scaffold the project. Trying a different generator might isolate the problem to the generator itself or yeoman. If you try this `npm i -g generator-angular` and then cd into the app directory and run `yo angular` does it install correctly?

Comment: Yes, this worked. It was missing karma, so I installed it. Ran this command that I found in git: npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular. Everything installed into /app folder. Now will have to tackle angular-fullstack.